# Correctness of an implementation beyond the methods signature contract of an interface

Tags: object-oriented-design, programming-practices

Is there a programming principle/guideline that tackles the correctness of a implementation beyond the methods signature contract of an interface?

Let's say we have a repository interface with two implementations, one of them is in memory, one of them is a database

The in memory one implements the interface with a list as the persistence mechanism, on `findById(int id)` method for example, loops over the list and returns the item with the specified id, basically the same instance that was saved prior.

In the case the SQL implementation, the sql queries the DB and makes **new** instance of that object, because it's "mapping" the tables onto the object.

A client of this repository interface, could get from the in memory repo a entity based on a id and modify it's properties, because it gave the instance from the list, it's already persisted, without the explicit use a method of the repository interface to save/persist the instance.
In the case of the SQL this wouldn't work.

Another problem could be of the identity, if you are unit testing your code, you would use the In-Memory implementation for predictability and so on. The client (unit-test) could get away with a entity1 == entity2 , this is going to check refference (pointer/memory address), not the identity of the entity itself.

Here is some code that can recreate this behaivour

```
interface ProductRepositoryInterface{
     Product getProductByID();
     void saveProduct(Product p);
}
```

```
class InMemoryProductRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface{
   private List<Product> productsList; 

   public InMemoryProductRepository (){
     this.productsList = new List<Products>();
   }  


   public getProductByID(int id){
       return productsList.findFirst(item -> item.id == id);
   } 

   public saveProduct(Product p){
   
   
   productsList.add(p);

   }

}
```

```
class SQLProductRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface{
   private SQLconnection conn;

   public InMemoryProductRepository (){
    this.conn = ... //connect to database
   }  


   public getProductByID(int id){
        conn.query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID = @id");
        // query the db
        return new Product(result.id, result.name ... );
   } 

   public saveProduct(Product p){

     conn.query("INSERT INTO Products (id,name ...) VALUES (@id, @name ...)");
        // insert into the db
   }
}
```

Note that the In-Memory implementation, returns a instance and SQL returns a **new** instance.

A client of the ProductRepositoryInterface could get away with `basketProducts.contains(product)`, assuming the products in the `basketProducts`, and `product` are instances got from the in-memory repository, but if we switch to the SQL Repository everything like this breaks down, and if your tests are written in this manner they could pass just fine with the in memory implementation of the repository.

Comment: "Is there a programming principle/guideline that tackles the correctness of a implementation beyond the methods signature contract of an interface?" - Yes! This is *exactly* what Liskov Substitution Principle is about. Online, you'll find a lot of handwavy statements about LSP, but the idea comes from a computer science paper by Barbara Liskov and Jeannette Wing. The paper defines what it means for something to be a behavioral subtype of something else. If you write a set of tests that *define* the correct abstract behavior, both your implementations must pass this *same* set of tests.

Comment: "client of this repository interface, could get from the in memory repo a entity based on a id and modify its properties, because it gave the instance from the list, it's already persisted" - you'd mock the repository, and replace it with what's called a "spy" (a kind of test double that can verify if a method on it was called or not, etc.); you'd then write tests for the client that *specify* that the client must call save on the repository; that is, any implementation of the client that doesn't do this is incorrect, and the tests should fail.

Comment: `A client of the ProductRepositoryInterface could get away with basketProducts.contains(product), assuming the products in the basketProducts, and product are instances got from the in-memory repository` how can they "assume" anything? The only they have is an interface... Are you trying to prevent from implementing code smell yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern, mainstream object-oriented languages like Java or C# don't have much that goes beyond the type signatures.

There are paradigms that specifically emphasize making broader guarantees about a computation. The biggest one right now would be stronger type systems as in Haskell or Idris. Type Theory and Dependent Types would be good places to look. The goal of such systems is to make invalid states impossible to represent in code.

Alternatively, Design-by-Contract languages like Eiffel allowed you to annotate code with invariants, pre and post conditions.

Java doesn't offer these sorts of facilities, which brings us around to what Steve McConnell called "program[ming] into your language."

> Don't limit your programming thinking only to the concepts that are supported automatically in your language. The best programmers think of what they want to do, and then they assess how to accomplish their objectives with the programming tools at their disposal.

(McConnell, *Code Complete*, chapter 34.3)

You can probably implement your own patterns to accomplish your ends. Alternatively, you might go looking for a framework that implements these sorts of features in your language of choice. For example, [OVal](https://sebthom.github.io/oval/USERGUIDE.html) is a framework that attempts to bring some design-by-contract concepts to Java. It may or may not be what you're looking for, but knowing the concepts allows you to look for community implementations that allow you to program into your language.

Answer (score 3):

'Correctness' in Software Engineering is defined in the context of some specification. For strongly typed languages like Haskell and Erlang, an adherence to the Type is itself often the definition of correctness. But in other, 'looser' languages, correctness is often defined through something like Unit Test and TDD/BDD where we have a suite of tests that poke and prod to make sure given some *I* we always get the right *O*.

In your example, there are 3 different specifications that I can see:

- The Repository Interface Specification
- An InMemory Repository Specification
- A SQL Repository Specification.

Typically, we start at the top, with the most generic specification that defines a bare-minimum set of expectations. Behaviors like "A new/updated object I save should affect subsequent retrieval" and "When an object can't be saved...*X* happens". Once you have those behaviors defined, you can feel (more) confident about referencing your Repository via its interface/base/delegating type.

Meanwhile, the tests for correctness for the concrete implementations also need to meet those standards, but also any additional logic you've specified. Note however, that your SQL repository has an explicit dependency on an 'external' system, so it can sometimes be redundant to try to test that in TDD, but we should include that testing behavior in our integration/smoke tests before deploying our application.

Going just a little bit further, a caller retrieving an object from a repository shouldn't have to worry/know that an object is new or not only that the object was persisted and is available. The onus is on a Repository to produce an object that meets the requirements of the caller or inform the caller that no such object is available.

Answer (score 1):

"Doctor, my arm hurts when I go like this", as Groucho said, "then don't go like that".

```
public saveProduct(Product p){   
    productsList.add( new Product(p) );
}
```

Mock the DB like this and reference comparisons should fail just like they'll fail for the DB. Yes this may mean forcing `Product` to have a copy constructor. That's what it means to write testable code. This presumes that `Product` is encapsulated. If not:

```
public saveProduct(Product p){   
    productsList.add( new Product(p.getId(), p.getName() ... ) );
}
```

Or, if `Product` is encapsulated, and you really don't want to add a copy constructor, you can always read products fields with reflection.

Comment: Don't forget to create deep copies of `Product` when filtering, so that clients cannot bypass `repository.save(product)`

Comment: @Laiv that would be an advantage of having a copy constructor.